# Same Entity for Web Api and WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have entities that uses for WCF service at the moment.

Sample like

```
[DataContract]
    public class Student
    {
        [DataMember]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    }
```

So all the properties are exposed to WCF at the moment. I want to use the same class for a wep api service but not exposed all the fields.

I know that need to use `[IgnoreDataMember]` for default XML serializer to it to be ignored but then it will have impact on current wcf service.

Is there a better way to handle this

Comment: If modifying the current entity is going to impact other technologies then that is a good sign that you have to create another entity.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to keep both classes with the same "fields" you can create an Interface to "link" them

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple helper class that will contain all the functions needed to shape the response object and control the object graph returned to the client. Use Factory pattern that will help in shaping and controlling the response returned to the client, so you can create a simplified model for some of domain object model that you have in DataBase. See below

Create a view model

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a Factory class as below

```
public class ModelFactory
{
    public StudentViewModel Create(model )
    {
        return new StudentViewModel
        {
           Id = model.Id;
           Name = model.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

In your webAPI controller define a property

```
    private ModelFactory _modelFactory;

    protected ModelFactory TheModelFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_modelFactory == null)
            {
                _modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
            }
            return _modelFactory;
        }
    }
```

After this from GET method you can call the custom object

```
Public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
{
 Student model = new Student();
 //Fetch data from DB and assign it to model
 return Ok(TheModelFactory.Create(model));
}
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. - This is the approach I follow.